# Can a disconnected set disconnect a connected set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $V$ is a connected open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $V\setminus F$ is disconnected, can we conclude that $F\cap V$ is connected? The answer for $n=1$ is obviously no and we can take as a counter example $V=\mathbb{R}$ and $F=[-1,0]\cup[1,2]$, for example. But what if $n>1$? Is the answer still no?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$ let $V=\{(x,y):1\lt x^2+y^2\lt4$ and $F=\{(x,y):y=0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:x_n=0 \text{ or } x_n=1\}$. Then $V\setminus F$ and $V\cap F$ are disconnected.