# Can a disconnected set disconnect a connected set 2?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

See [Can a disconnected set disconnect a connected set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3898672/can-a-disconnected-set-disconnect-a-connected-set). In the given counter examples $F$ is unbounded. I change a little the same question. Suppose $V$ is a connected open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>1$ and $F$ a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $V\setminus F$ is disconnected, can $F$ have a "bounded component" meaning  $\partial V\cap F=\emptyset$? ($\partial V$ is the boundary of $V$)

Comment: @Arthur. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you say $F$ having a bounded component means $\partial V\cap F=\emptyset$?

Comment: Of course this is not a definition, but this is the analogue of what happens in $[-\infty,\infty]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $V$ to be the ball of radius $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $F = \mathbb{S}^1 = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \subset V$. Then $V \setminus F$ has two components and $\partial V \cap F = \varnothing$.